# UNPIVOT a presto table

Tags: sql, presto, unpivot

I am very new to SQL with presto and trying to unpivot a table that looks like this:
[Pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qCNb.png) to make it look like this: [Unpivoted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdrky.png)

I have tried using UNPIVOT function, I have tried CROSS JOINING with unnest. I finally thought I had figured it out using UNION but I can quiet get the query right. Could you please push me in the right direction?

This is what I was working on:

```
SELECT CASE_ID, Account, Amount 
FROM 
TEST_TABLE 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (
ARRAY['Factor_Cost','Unfactor_cost'],
ARRAY[Factor_Cost,Unfactor_cost]
) t2(account, amount)
```

Thanks so much,
R

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. It can be done using cross join + case expression to calculate amount depending on account value:

```
SELECT t1.CASE_ID, 
       t2.Account,
       case when t2.Account = 'Factor_Cost' then t1.factor_cost else t1.unfactor_cost end  Amount 
FROM 
TEST_TABLE t1 
CROSS JOIN (
values('Factor_Cost'),('Unfactor_cost')
) t2(account)
```

Cross join will duplicate rows by account values and CASE expression it to take corresponding column from t1 as Amount.

Or the same using CROSS JOIN UNNEST, without CASE expression:

```
SELECT t1.CASE_ID, 
       t2.Account,
       t2.Amount 
FROM 
TEST_TABLE t1 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
ARRAY['Factor_Cost','Unfactor_cost'],
ARRAY[t1.factor_cost,t1.unfactor_cost]
) t2(account,amount)
```

Or the same using UNION ALL (less efficient approach)

```
SELECT CASE_ID, 'Factor_Cost' Account, factor_cost Amount from TEST_TABLE t1 
union all
SELECT CASE_ID, 'Unfactor_cost' Account, unfactor_cost Amount from TEST_TABLE t1
```

All these queries can produce results ordered differently. only using additional ORDER BY can guarantee the same order.

Comment: I am using the first one and getting this error. Sorry, like I said I am not very experienced with SQL. "line 14:5: mismatched input 't2'. Expecting: ',', 'EXCEPT', 'FROM', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INTERSECT', 'LIMIT', 'OFFSET', 'ORDER', 'UNION', 'WHERE', <EOF> TAAL[BLAME_dirs,www/flib/presto/]"

Comment: @RohitAnand so strange The code in my answer is tested, it works on Presto